# Aligning equations in a system of equations with inside arrows

Tags: align, arrows

I wrote the code:

```
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
\text{Risorsa occupata $\quad \Leftrightarrow$} \quad s &= 0 \\
\text{Risorsa libera $\quad \Leftrightarrows$} \quad s &= 1
\end{empheq}
```

but Texmaker gives me an error. If I rewrite it as follows:

```
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
\text{Risorsa occupata $\quad \Leftrightarrow$} \quad s &= 0 \\
\quad s &= 1
\end{empheq}
```

it works. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of `cases`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{cases} 
\text{Risorsa occupata} & \Leftrightarrow  s = 0 \\
\text{Risorsa libera}   & \Leftrightarrow  s = 1
\end{cases} 
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @leandriis